# How to clear up the data after I use PlotWidget.plot()?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class MyGraph(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraph, self).__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)

        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')

        x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

        self.pw = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.pw.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='o', symbolBrush='r')

        self.plot_btn = QPushButton('Replot', self)
        self.plot_btn.clicked.connect(self.plot_slot)

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.pw)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.plot_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)

    def plot_slot(self):
        x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

        # The new data is added to the existed one
        self.pw.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='o', symbolBrush='r')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = MyGraph()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Every time I clicked the button, I want to clean the existed data and replot the new one, but PlotWidget doesn't seem to have the relative function to let me do that.

Is there any way I can clean the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot method of PlotWidget generates an item that is responsible for drawing, in your case each time you press the button another plot is created so you observe that 
behavior. The solution is to reuse

```py
class MyGraph(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraph, self).__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)

        pg.setConfigOption("background", "w")

        x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

        self.pw = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.plot = self.pw.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol="o", symbolBrush="r")

        self.plot_btn = QPushButton("Replot", self, clicked=self.plot_slot)

        v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.pw)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.plot_btn)

    def plot_slot(self):
        x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        self.plot.setData(x, y)
```